# Set table to a certain position that does not change during Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

In HTML, I have a div that contains a table of labels and textboxes

[image: Before writing in password textbox]

the following HTML code belongs to the 'td' that contains the 'Password':

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" onkeyup="return passwordChanged();"></asp:TextBox>
<span id="strengthID"></span>
```

passwordChanged is a javascript function to determine the strength of the password. This function changes the innerHTML of the span 'strengthID'

My problem is simple: when 'stengthID' changes its content (on onkeyup event), the whole table shifts left.

[image: After writing in password textbox]

My goal is to keep everything as it is while changing the inner text of the span. I couldn't get rid of this behavior. Please can you point to some possible css attribute I would need to use? or any other suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to specify wdith for your first column.

for example

```
<td style="width:150px;">
```

specifying width for any row's first column will do the job

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a fixed width on that td, otherwise the browser will adjust the width depending on the content of the columns.

One way to do it would be to add a class to the first td on each row (even on just one row will be sufficient) and call it `label` for instance.

Then add some CSS:

```
.label {
   width: 123px; /* Some width of your choice */
}
```